# Is there a method to instantly, dynamically switch between several sets of name servers on a single domain with code?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I usually set name servers at an ISP, they often take 24 - 48 hours to resolve. If one has 2 separate sets of name servers (say from 2 domain parking companies) they want to send traffic to, is it possible to switch between the sets instantly without any delays?

To be clear, how do you switch `mydomain.com (ns1.nameserver1.com, ns2.nameserver1.com)` to `mydomain.com (ns1.nameserver2.com, ns2.nameserver2.com)` instantly?

Answer (score 3):

You can't switch "instantly", this isn't possible with the DNS protocol. You can set a very low timeout on your DNS records, but you still be dependent on the good will of the other DNS servers to retrieve your records.